# How can I close an opened HTML document in Android application?

Tags: android, python

I opened the document with this line:

```
droid.webViewShow('file:///...').result
```

I would like to close it after a few seconds. I didn't find any working code for it.
I need just some short line codes.

I'm beginnert with android and python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure of the exact context of your snippet of code, but if you are opening your own HTML file that you have access to, you can go into the HTML and add a "close page" button that will send a signal to the python script to exit.

To create the button, add this to the HTML file somewhere:

```
<button id="close" type="button"
    onclick="droid.eventPost('close', '')"
>
    Close Page</button>
```

This will create a button that will send an event titled 'close' to the python script when clicked.

Now to keep the page open for as long as you like, add an infinite loop to your code below the .webViewShow() call that will run until it recognizes that the button was clicked.

In order for the script to recognize the button click, you need to add a line that waits for an event to be sent to the script, then just use an if statement to check for the correct event, 'close' in this case.

```
#infinite loop to keep page open
while(True):

    #wait for event (from button)
    event = droid.eventWait().result

    #check for desired event  (close)
    if (event['name'] == 'close'):

        #exit
        sys.exit()
```

Overall, it's a pretty crude solution. Good luck.